# I don't understand the decimal to binary code

Tags: binary, decimal, pascal, freepascal

decimal 45 is 101101 in binary, when I have to explain the code I get to 1011001, but program outputs the right answer. Where does this 0 go 10110 **0** 1 after 2 mod 2 = 0?

I followed the steps in program if I type 45 as decimal number:

- 45 mod 2 = 1, x = "1"
- " " + "1" = "1"
- 45 div 2 = 22
- 22 mod 2 = 1, x = "0"
- "1" + "0" = "10"
- 22 div 2 = 11
- 11 mod 2 = 1, x = "1"
- "10" + "1" = "101"
- 11 div 2 = 5
- 5 mod 2 = 1, x = "1"
- "101" + "1" = "1011"
- 5 div 2 = 4
- 4 mod 2 = 0, x = "0"
- "1011" + "0" = "10110"
- 4 div 2 = 2
- 2 mod 2 = 0, x = "0"
- "10110" + "0" = "101100"
- 2 div 2 = 1
- 1 mod 2 = 1, x = "1"
- "101100" + "1" = "1011001"
- 1 div 2 = 0
- program ends

How it still outputs 101101?!

```
    write('Enter decimal number: ');
    readln(dec);
    repeat 
    if (dec mod 2 = 0) then x:= '0' 
    else x:= '1'; 
    bin:= bin + x; 
    dec:= dec div 2;
    until dec= 0; 
    writeln(bin);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this line:

```
5 div 2 = 4
```

It equals 2, not 4.

You also have a typo here:

```
22 mod 2 = 1, x = "0"
```